# Careers messages for employers seems to replace my job seeker messages

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

Interesting issue here that I don't think most people will run into.

On the careers site, if I've sent out 3 applications I would typically be able to see that message list ("for job seekers" view). However, I've posted a job to the site just last night and the 5 applicants I've gotten have shown up-- but my old "job seeker" view has vanished.

You probably didn't expect employers to also be job seekers, but that's the situation I'm in. Both "views" take me to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/messages .

The impact is I can't really use the site to do a job search while looking to hire someone.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: There is now only a single messages page and this is no longer an issue.

---

If you have messages or applications sent to you as an employer, the link at the top will always direct you to the employer messages page.  You can still view your candidate side messages by going to your profile page and clicking the messages tab in the sidebar.

This is a sort of funny case right now, and *very* soon you will have a much more streamlined experience when it comes to messages from both sides.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a link to that page from the messages page? I found this really confusing.

Comment: @Incognito It would be, but in a week or so it won't matter, so I'll defer the request until then.